# Doing an image slider from scratch

Tags: jquery, css, html, slider, position

I am working on an image slider. What I'm actually trying to do is placing the images one right by the side of the other, but I've been trying to do that with `display: inline-block`, also `float:left`...but none of them seems to work and I don't know why. I'll leave you the JS fiddle to see if someone can help me. I would like to do it using `display inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

### Html Code

```
<body>
<div id='window'>
    <div id='slide-window'>
        <ul id='slides'>
            <li class='slide'><img src="http://files.chess.com/images_ads/chesscom_logo_on_dark-copy.png"></li>
            <li class='slide'><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykt9V.png"></li>
            <li class='slide'><img src="https://raw.github.com/andrew-yavtushenko/css-style-guide/master/dog.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

### Css Code

```
#slide-window
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
}

#slides
{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}

#slides li
{   
float: left; 
position: relative;
left: 0;
top:0;
}

#window
{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background: black;
margin: 2em auto 0 auto;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/EbjWS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow:hidden` on `#window` and give `#slide-window` the same width as the total width of all your images.

Comment: ohh thank you very much!...that worked really good....with float: left; it works really good but with display: inline-block; it adds some kind of margin of something so i have to set the #slide-window to 1210px instead of 1200px...do you now why is that happening?

Comment: Could be due to the white space between the elements. Try running them together like `</li><li>` or put comments between them like `</li><!-- --><li>`.

Comment: li elements have margin and padding by default, you will need to reset those to zero with css, same for the parent ul